# Получение данных с сервера с помощью Retrofit 2

Tags: android, retrofit2

Изучаю разработку по андроид. 
Пытаюсь получуть данные с сервера по этому уроку https://startandroid.ru/ru/blog/506-retrofit.html

Если в эмулаторе открываю версию 5.0.0, то все работает и выводит response 50.
Если версию 4.4.4, то в логах ошибка:
failure javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: javax.net.ssl.SSLProtocolException: SSL handshake aborted: ssl=0xb7bb6098: Failure in SSL library, usually a protocol error
    error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure (external/openssl/ssl/s23_clnt.c:741 0x96ead926:0x00000000)

По аналитике гугла, минимальная версия используемого андроид у нас в компании 4.4.4.
Как подружить эту версию с Retrofit?

Comment: на реальных девайсах не пробовали? возможно проблема в эмуляторе

Comment: а библиотеки последние юзаете?

Comment: @iFr0z поледние

Comment: @EugeneZaychenko нет реальных устройств на 4.4.4 под рукой

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/36892715